# MIP Python School Teacher Timetabling problem - how to check if the number of variables equals zero is equal to a certain number

Tags: python, optimization, scheduling

I'm trying to solve a School Teacher Time problem. I'm at a good point but now I'm stuck at how to model that each teacher have a certain number of free days in a week e.g. the sum of days with zero lesson for each teacher is equal to a certain number.

Basic the question is: How I can add a contraint that count the number of time that a variable is equal to 0.0 ?

y count the number of hours that teacher teach every day.
More or less ought to be something like this (but doesn't work, of course)

```
for t in teacher:
    model += xsum( y[t, d] == 0.0 for d in day ) == 1.0
```

I tried also using the actual value of the variable:

```
for t in teacher:
    model += xsum( y[t, d].x == 0.0 for d in day ) == 1.0
```

and:

```
for t in teacher:
    model += xsum( y[t, d] for d in day if y[t, d] == 0.0 ) == 1.0
```

But none seems to work.

I can share some code but actually everything is written in Italian so I tried to boil down straight to the point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you want to solve this with a (linear) MIP solver, your attempts are violating linearity. Here is what you can try:

Let `y[t,d]` be the number of hours of teacher `t` in day `d`. Let's assume it is an integer variable. Then we can define the binary variable:

```
 x[t,d] = 1  if t works at d
        = 0  is t is off at d
```

The link between x and y can be modeled as:

```
 x[t,d] <= y[t,d]     (y[t,d]=0 => x[t,d]=0)
 8*x[t,d] >= y[t,d]   (y[t,d]>0 => x[t,d]=1, assuming 8 hours is the maximum per day)
```

Now we can say (in pseudo code):

```
 sum(d, 1-x[t,d]) = 1   (exactly one day off)
```

or maybe:

```
 sum(d, x[t,d]) = 4     (exactly 4 days at work)
```

Comment: Thank you @erwin I must deep think at how to apply your good solution, but I got the point. And yes, of course, I forgot to specify I'm using MIP on python.

Comment: Hi  @erwin I tried to cast your solution in MIP but I don't understand how to implement the x[t,d] variable definition. I wrote:
`
x = {
    (t, d): model.add_var(
        name="x({},{})".format(t, d),
        var_type=BINARY
    )
    for t in teacher
    for d in day
}
for t in teacher:
    for d in day:
        x[t,d] = y[t,d]/8
`
And in this way x[t,d] populates with values ranging from zero to one not just zero and one. By example 0,6 0.4 but non 0 or 1 as I need

Comment: You probably should show the complete code. I don't think I have ever used Python-MIP, but I am sure some users will be able to help out.

Comment: Note that `var_type=BINARY` should not allow fractional values. That would be integer infeasible.

Answer (score 0):

The @erwin solution works from a theorical POV, so I accept it, but I can't be able to cast in MIP Python code.

So I found some other solutions, that are not perfect for some ways, but I put here for reference for other mates.
And of course I will share the code as soon as I translate in english. BTW I'm looking for an academic team mate in academic world for writing a scientific article (@erwin ?) or a medium article or both and release all the code in open source.

Let's back to the problem.
I found 3 Hard Costraint solution ad 1 Soft Costraint solution. I show all solutions so someone could use it

HC solution 1 - The elegant one

I can simply add an Hard Costraint that y[t,d] <= 0.0 for that combination of teacher, day of the week that I want to be off.

```
for t in self.teacher:
    for d in self.day:
        if t,d in self.desiderata:
            self.model += self.y[t, d] <= 0.0
```

(BTW this is a simplified version because desiderata is a structured dicionary but I think you got the point)

Right to the point, and works soooo great !

But I know can do better, I can avoid also to use y[t,d] because is a derivate variable so i can avoid it and improve performances.

HC solution 2 - The better performances solution

Because y[t,d] is in effect a derivated variable from the original variable x[t, g, m, d, h] where:

```
self.x = {
    (t, g, m, d, h): self.model.add_var(
        name="x({},{},{},{},{})".format(t, g, m, d, h),
        var_type=BINARY
    )
    for t in self.teacher
    for g in self.grade
    for m in self.matter
    for d in self.day
    for h in self.hour
}
```

and:

```
self.y = {
    (t, d): self.model.add_var(
        name="y({},{})".format(t, d),
        var_type=BINARY
    )
    for t in self.teacher
    for d in self.day
}

for t in self.teacher:
    for d in self.day:
        self.y[t,d] = xsum( self.x[t, g, m, d, h] 
                                for h in self.hour
                                for m in self.matter
                                for g in self.grade)
```

So basically, y[t,d] sums how much hours a teacher t works in a specific day d.
In effect I don't need y[t,d] because I can write straight the constraint in this way:

```
for t in teacher:
    for d in self.day:
        if t,d in self.desiderata:
            self.model += xsum(self.x[t, g, m, d, h] 
                               for g in self.grade 
                               for m in self.matter 
                               for h in self.hour) <= 0.0
```

And ..... OMG this works too ! that's wonderfull

This ought to lead to better performances because the problem in NP-Complete so reducing the variables number reduce the time to resolve.

But I'm sure I can improve it.
Why I add the variable x[t, g, m, d, h] also for combination of t,d where that teacher have the day off ?
If I don't generate x[t, g, m, d, h] the problem is resolved by default without any other constraint. Let's try:

HC Solution 3 - The faster one

Basically, the generation of variable x take in account the day off for each teacher:

```
self.x = {
    (t, g, m, d, h): self.model.add_var(
        name="x({},{},{},{},{})".format(t, g, m, d, h),
        var_type=BINARY
    )
    for t in self.teacher
    for g in self.grade
    for m in self.matter
    for d in self.day
    for h in self.hour
    if not (t,d in self.desiderata) # Each teacher not work in days off
}
```

And without add any other constraint this works too !!! just out of the box !

This lead me to 18% of variables not generated. And remember, the problem in NP-Complete so this is a huge improvement !

So I have 3 different full working Hard Constraint solutions but there's a catch, because this approach could lead easily to an infeasible solution, if days off conflicting too much.

With code, I can relax days off one after the other, but this way is not anymore a pure MIP problem.

Why not use the Objective Function ?

So let's insert the count of days off matching in Objective Function.

SC - Maximize the days off

Let's use y[t,d] for clarity, but consider that we can drop it and use x instead if we need to.

```
self.model.objective = minimize( 
    xsum( self.y[t,d] for t in self.teacher for d in self.day if t,d in self.desiderata )
)
```

And works very fine too !!!

In the code I will share ASAP, there's some code optimization principally to reduce the number of variables but the concept are express over ther.

Thank you for reading all this long reply.

Comment: As promised, here's the medium article: https://medium.com/@gianfrancotavella/school-scheduling-with-mip-6aed8f9a9d26 and here's the full working code: https://github.com/gt1967/MIP-School-Timetabling